# Unity "are you missing a using directive" on a using directive

Tags: unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code

I run into this problem every few months and it annoys the crap out of me. I do not understand what causes this or how I seem to keep fixing it. But every once and awhile I will update Unity, switch git branches or something and then all of a sudden Unity can not find packages imported from GitHub.

I can see that the libraries are in my unity packages folder but Unity can not see them. Here you can see MyBox and xNode are in my Unity Packages folder.

[image]

The funny thing about the error, highlighted below, is that the line of code it is complaining about possibly not having a using directive for xNodeEditor... is a using directive for xNodeEditor...

Here is the error I am getting for that line.  "Assets\Editor\xNode\DialogueNodeEditor.cs(2,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'XNodeEditor' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

[image]

I don't think this is a namespace issue as I don't use namespaces. I am sorry I can't provide more information I do not know what I did recently to my project before this started again.

Not sure if this is relevant but here is my GameAssembly where you can see MyBox and xNode are present.

[image]

Comment: Viewing this post from behind a corporate proxy that doesn't allow imgur inks shows me a post with a run-on paragraph of text and a lot of missing spaces where you've apparently included nothing but images. It is also very difficult to read and understand when using a mobile device because there's no meaningful content that isn't an image.

Comment: There I edited the question for ya. I hope it does not run on too much for ya.

Comment: Well I can't provide the dream solution, there is a work around for me. I find often references get broken when switching branches. It seems if I close Unity, switch, then reopen, most of my problems are gone. Annoying, yes, better than broken, yes.

Comment: @Derek I think that might be a partial solution. Unity has stopped throwing the errors seen above after reopening Unity. But VSCode still shows these errors when hovering over methods from the xNode library. The weird part is that the game seems to be working fine its just syntax highlighting and IntelliSense now is not working. Which makes development annoying.

Comment: Ah, I might know what's up hold on I'll make an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I stated in the comments, closing Unity before switching branches seems to help minimise how much Unity freaks out.
After, if VS is no longer recognising libraries in your code / Unity's built in scripts it may have to do with not opening the SLN file.
[Here](https://github.com/DerekCresswell/GameDesign11/blob/master/2%20Dice%20Game/1%20UnityScripts.md#important-note-for-visual-studios) is a part of a tutorial I wrote as this problem occurred on the school computers.
If VS says "Miscellaneous Files" just under the scripts name tabs it has not properly opened the Unity files. Fix this by closing VS and opening by clicking in Unity "Assets" then "Open C# Project" it may prompt you to specify a SLN file.

Even if VS does not say the files are misc it seems to help to open via assets rather than double clicking a script.

Comment: Thanks, I think I figured it out. I recently changed my game Product Name. The .sln file still had the name of the old Product. I changed the name to be correct and restarted VSCode. Now all the errors have gone away.